# Finding cosets of a sub group of the polynomials

Tags: group-theory

Given the group $G=(\mathbb{R}_2[x],+)$, and a sub group of $G$: $H=\{p(x)\in G:p(1)=0\}$, what are $H$'s cosets?

Thanks.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{R}_2$ ?

Comment: Edit: Nevermind, question already asked.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}_2[x]$ is the vector space (and so also a group) of all polynomials of degree 2 or less (including the zero polynomial).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

Assuming $\,G\,$ is the group of all real polynomials of degree two or less (and the zero polynomial, of course) , then

$$(1)\;\;\;p(x)\in H\iff p(1)=0\iff (x-1)\mid p(x)\iff p(x)=(x-1)g(x)\;,\;g(x)\in\Bbb R_2[x]$$

$$(2)\;\;\;\text{For}\;f(x)\,,\,g(x)\in\Bbb R_2[x]\;:\;f(x)+H=g(x)+H\iff$$

$$\iff f(x)-g(x)\in H\iff f(x)=(x-1)h(x)+g(x)\iff f(1)=g(1)\ldots$$